# Use the same workbook in multiple modules

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two buttons. So an user can press them to open two workbooks (Input and Output). Then he will copy data from Input to Output. My problem here is that I don't know how to define the same workbook for my subs.
[image]

This is the code for opening the files:

```
Public wb1 As Workbook
Public wb2 As Workbook
Public result As Integer
Public fDialog As FileDialog

Public Sub inputs()
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Set control = Workbooks("Control.xlsm").Worksheets("Control")
fDialog.Title = "Select a file"

fDialog.Title = "Select a file"

 If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
    If Right(fDialog.SelectedItems(1), 5) = ".xlsx" Or Right(fDialog.SelectedItems(1), 4) = ".xls" Then
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fDialog.SelectedItems(1))
        control.Cells(6, 2) = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please select an excel file")
        Exit Sub
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

This is the other sub for copying data:

```
Public Sub stack()
 For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
  '---here is the code for copying data---
 Exit For 
Exit Sub
```

When I run this code, of course it gives me this error "object variable or With block not set".
Do you know how can I resolve this? How can I use the same wb1 for both subs?

Comment: 1) Declare `wb1` as a module-level variable, `Private wb1 As Workbook` at the top of the module (outside of all sub) OR 2) Define `wb1` manually in the `stack` sub (the path is written in a cell, right?) Note: It is good practice to declare all variables, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to enforce that.

Comment: Hello! I have declared them but I didn't add them here because I wanted to keep yhe code "clean". See my edit above. I have declared them public and I have the same error

Comment: What does "the same workbook" means? You are talking about two workbooks (Input and Output)... Don't you refer at these workbooks? If yes, wouldn't exist two such workbook variables? Then, when you use `fDialog`, you must set the window title. For users and for us to understand what workbook do you try defining.

Comment: Did you run `inputs` then `stack` right after? the state of public variables will be lost if you reset or end while testing. Personally I prefer you modify `stack` sub to define `wb1` within it so that it is not dependent on a public variable being defined.

Comment: In the second Sub I need to work with both workbooks (Input and Output) opened in the first Sub. I have added the window title, sorry

Comment: Why not prompt for both workbooks in `stack` sub and define them internally? If the workflow is [Select input wb] -> [Select output wb] -> [Copy Data], I don't see why you want to have multiple buttons for it.

Comment: @RaymondWu Yes I run it right after. How would you define wb1 in sub Stack? This may solve my problem

Comment: Because when I run the stack sub that window (to open wb) will be showing every time

Comment: Please, try the solution I proposed and send some feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to limit the scope of your variable whenever possible so what you can do is this:

```
Public Sub stack()
    Dim wbControl As Worksheet
    Set wbControl = Workbooks("Control.xlsm").Worksheets("Control")

    'Check if there is possible input path in cell B6
    If wbControl.Cells(6, 2).Value2 = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Provide the Input workbook path first!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Check if there is possible output path in cell B6
    If wbControl.Cells(6, 2).Value2 = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Provide the Output workbook path first!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'More error checking - e.g. check if both path are valid (file exist?)
            
    Dim wbInput As Workbook
    Set wbInput = Workbooks.Open(wbControl.Cells(6, 2).Value2) 'Input path in cell B6
    
    Dim wbOutput As Workbook
    Set wbOutput = Workbooks.Open(wbControl.Cells(6, 5).Value2) 'Output path in cell E6
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wbInput.Worksheets
        'Do whatever you want in here
    Next ws
    
    'Remember to close the workbook if not needed later
End Sub
```

Remove this line from your `inputs` sub (and also similar one for selecting the output file)

`Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fDialog.SelectedItems(1))`

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is exactly what I needed and now it's more clear

Comment: @Dodoi I recommend that before opening the workbooks, check that the file in the given path 1) actually exist (You can use `Dir` for that, plenty of examples so google for it); and 2) is a file that Excel can open (so maybe just `xlsx` for your case) so that you don't get an error when Excel is attempting to open it.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I will take a better look regarding what you've said

Answer (score 3):

Please, use the next way:

1. Declare public variables for both necessary workbooks, on top of the standard module:

```
Public wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
```

2. Copy the next sub in a **standard module**, to open and `Set` the necessary workbooks:

```
Sub SetWorbooks()
Dim fdialog As FileDialog, i As Long
Set fdialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 For i = 1 To 2
    fdialog.Title = "Please, select """ & IIf(i = 1, "Input", "Output") & """ file"
    
     If fdialog.Show = -1 Then
        If Right(fdialog.SelectedItems(1), 5) = ".xlsx" Or Right(fdialog.SelectedItems(1), 4) = ".xls" Then
            If i = 1 Then
                Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fdialog.SelectedItems(1))
            Else
                Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fdialog.SelectedItems(1))
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select an excel file (xls, xlsx)!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
     Else
           MsgBox "You should select an Excel file...": Exit Sub
     End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

3. Then use them in this way:

```
Sub Mystack()
Dim ws As Worksheet

If wb1 Is Nothing Then SetWorbooks 'for cases when having an error and the wb(s) reference have been lost.
 For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
  '---here is the code for copying data---
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is also working but I will choose to use the other variant provided by Raymond Wu.

Comment: @Dodoi No problem with me. This version already sets the two objects and your code can use them directly. It calls the `SetWorbooks` only if something wrong happened and the two objects lost their reference. This should happen very seldom or never, if your code(s) run(s) smooth...